# Изменить принцип шифрования

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу по стеганографии wav файлов. Помимо секретного сообщения в аудио необходимо встроить ключ, который считывается из файла. Помогите переделать код таким образом, чтобы ключ вставлялся сразу после служебных символов. После вставки ключа вставлялось бы сообщение и далее оставшаяся не измененная часть аудио файла. Или же при извлечении сообщения не будет возможности различить где ключ, а где само сообщение?

Код встраивания сообщения:

```
 public void Hide(Stream messageStream, Stream keyStream)
    {

        byte[] waveBuffer = new byte[_bytesPerSample];
        byte message, bit, waveByte;
        int messageBuffer; //receives the next byte of the message or -1
        int keyByte; //distance of the next carrier sample

        while ((messageBuffer = messageStream.ReadByte()) >= 0)
        {
            //read one byte of the message stream
            message = (byte)messageBuffer;

            //for each bit in message
            for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < 8; bitIndex++)
            {

                //read a byte from the key
                keyByte = GetKeyValue(keyStream);

                //skip a couple of samples
                for (int n = 0; n < keyByte - 1; n++)
                {
                    //copy one sample from the clean stream to the carrier stream
                    _sourceStream.Copy(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length, _destinationStream);
                }

                //read one sample from the wave stream
                _sourceStream.Read(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);
                waveByte = waveBuffer[_bytesPerSample - 1];

                //get the next bit from the current message byte...
                if ((message & (byte) (1 << bitIndex)) > 0)
                    bit = 1;
                else
                    bit = 0;

                //...place it in the last bit of the sample
                if ((bit == 1) && ((waveByte % 2) == 0))
                {
                    waveByte += 1;
                }
                else if ((bit == 0) && ((waveByte % 2) == 1))
                {
                    waveByte -= 1;
                }

                waveBuffer[_bytesPerSample - 1] = waveByte;

                //write the result to destinationStream
                _destinationStream.Write(waveBuffer, 0, _bytesPerSample);
            }
        }

        //copy the rest of the wave without changes
        waveBuffer = new byte[_sourceStream.Length - _sourceStream.Position];
        _sourceStream.Read(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);
        _destinationStream.Write(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);
    }
```

Операции с ключом:

```
public static long CheckKeyForMessage(Stream keyStream, long messageLength)
    {
        long messageLengthBits = messageLength * 8;
        long countRequiredSamples;

        if (messageLengthBits > keyStream.Length && keyStream.Length != 0)
        {
            long keyLength = keyStream.Length;

            // read existing key
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keyLength];
            keyStream.Read(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length);

            // Every byte stands for the distance between two useable samples.
            // The sum of those distances is the required count of samples.
            countRequiredSamples = SumKeyArray(keyBytes);                

            // The key must be repeated, until every bit of the message has a key byte.
            double countKeyCopies;
            countKeyCopies = messageLengthBits / keyLength;
            countRequiredSamples = (long)(countRequiredSamples * countKeyCopies);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[messageLengthBits];
            keyStream.Read(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length);
            countRequiredSamples = SumKeyArray(keyBytes);                
        }

        keyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return countRequiredSamples;
    }

    private static long SumKeyArray(byte[] values)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        foreach (int value in values)
        {
            // '0' causes a distance of one sample,
            // every other key causes a distance of its exact value.                
            if (value == 0)
                sum += 1;
            else                    
                sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the next byte of the key stream.
    /// Reset the stream if it is too short.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyStream">The key stream</param>
    /// <returns>The next key byte</returns>
    private static byte GetKeyValue(Stream keyStream)
    {
        int keyValue;
        if ((keyValue = keyStream.ReadByte()) < 0)
        {
            keyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            keyValue = keyStream.ReadByte();
            if (keyValue == 0) { keyValue = 1; }
        }
        return (byte)keyValue;
    }
```

Comment: Что-то не похоже, что это ваш код. Где вообще чтение заголовка wav файла?

Comment: Да, код позаимствован. Дабы не нагружать пост, чтение заголовка wav файла я опустил.